# facebook app invite integration with branch io

Tags: facebook, react-native, branch.io

I am having problem integrating branch io for facebook app invite.

I have followed steps required for branch io integration for facebook app invite but still I am getting "Missing App Link Url" Error.

I have authenticated branch io with facebook. 
I am using `branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(linkProperties, controlParams)` method to generate my url and then i am using this url in

```
appInviteContent: {
        applinkUrl: 'URL FROM BRANCH_IO'
}
```

Also when I paste this url in `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/`
I get [The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ye7i.png) warning.

Also, when I use app-link (generated through Mobile Hosting API service of facebook. Just to check the Facebook SDK Integration.) everything works fine. Here is [the scrape data of this app-link url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDeJV.png)

I want to send some info (e.g. - referral code ) with the app link that I am using for invite.

Am I missing anything in the process or doing wrong?
Can anyone provide me with the working code for the same in React-native?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: this is a known issue that comes up sometimes. We are not sure when or why, though it usually has something to do with the OG tags being structured in a way Facebook can't parse. You may have neglected to fully configure your Branch app with all the necessary fallback URLs.

There are troubleshooting and workaround steps for this issue available in the Branch documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-app-invites/support/ios/#issues-reading-facebook-app-links).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply. I went through the docs. I am unable to understand the meaning of 'append ?id'. For eg- If the url that I get from Branch.io is abc.com/sampleString, then do you want me to append just ?id to the url ( Final url - abc.com/sampleString?id ). An example would be great. Thanks Again!

Comment: I am using custom url for iOS Redirect.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo on that page...it should read as follows: If you are using a Custom URL for your iOS Redirect, then you need to append `?id[10-digit App Store ID]` to the URL. This is necessary in order to fully generate the App Links and OG tags that the Facebook scraper expects to find. For example, if your App Store URL is `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-app-name/id1234567890`, then your Custom URL value should be `https://example.com?id1234567890`

Comment: Hey Alex! Thanks again. I am kind of stuck in this for a very long time. Can you please guide me through the process if I don't have an App store ID. Actually, as of now my app is in development phase and we don't have Apple dev. account. I am using https://www.diawi.com/ to host my app.

Comment: You'll need an App Store ID to enable this because Facebook uses that ID to check the store and verify an app actually exists. You may be able to temporarily use the ID of another live app (not under your control) to test some parts of the process.